# Confusion Proving That a Discrete Probability Mass Function Sums to 1

Tags: probability

In a [section](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter3/3_1_3_pmf.php) in the https://www.probabilitycourse.com, this formula was provided:

> $P_Y(k) =P(Y=k)=(1-p)^{k-1} p, \textrm{ for } k=1,2,3,...$

Next, it goes on to show that:

> $\sum_{y \in R_Y} P_Y(y)=1$.

It starts with this expression:

> $\sum_{y \in R_Y} P_Y(y) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (1-p)^{k-1} p$

On the left of the expression, I was thinking $y \in R_Y$ represent a fixed range of discrete values and I was confused why the range of the expression on the right is from $k=1$ to $k= \infty$

As I'm typing this question, I'm now thinking that the expression on the left $y \in R_Y$ is from 1 to infinity based on the first expression where $k = 1,2,3, ...$?

How should I be thinking about this?  Simpler answers will be preferred over complex answers.

Comment: There is a probability associated with every $k = 1,2,3...$, all the way to $+\infty$, so you need to sum up all these cases. In other words, no matter how large $k$ becomes, I can always tell you that $P_Y(k)$ will occur with probability $(1-p)^{k-1}p$.

Comment: "Discrete" here does not mean finite.

Comment: Do you know how to sum geometric series?

Comment: @J.G. I don’t - but I will take a look.  Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show the PDF sums to one one should sum all of its values.
Yet the PDF might be defined only on a subset of value and not any value.

In the case above, the PDF only defined on the number $ 1, 2, 3, \ldots $ (Positive Integers).

Now, by definition the sum of PDF as a function of $ y $ is given by:

$$ \sum_{y \in \Omega} {P}_{Y} \left( y \right) $$

Where $ \Omega $ is the support (Sub set of $ \mathbb{R} $) where $ {P}_{Y} \left( \cdot \right) $ is defined.

As you pointed, above, in your case $ {R}_{y} = \left\{ 1, 2, 3, \ldots \right\} $.